# Convert the JSON data response as expected in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

```js
var mydata = [
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul1: 1004
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul2: 1234
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul3: 1034
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul4: 1204
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul5: 2234
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul6: 2234
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul7: 2034
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul8: 2412
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul9: 2502
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul10: 1122
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul1: 1034
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul2: 1304
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul3: 1230
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul4: 2234
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul5: 2234
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul6: 2224
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul7: 2232
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul8: 1434
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul9: 1244
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul10: 1234
  }
];
```

Is that possible to convert the above JSON as Below JSON? the data above JSON that come from backend response data. Have to convert as below JSON

```js
var dataneeded = [
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: ">RT-113, <RT-333",
    jul1: 1004,
    jul2: 1234,
    jul3: 1034,
    jul4: 1204,
    jul5: 2234,
    jul6: 2234,
    jul7: 2034,
    jul8: 2412,
    jul9: 2502,
    jul10: 1122
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: ">GF-103, <GF-303",
    jul1: 1034,
    jul2: 1304,
    jul3: 1230,
    jul4: 2234,
    jul5: 2234,
    jul6: 2224,
    jul7: 2232,
    jul8: 1434,
    jul9: 1244,
    jul10: 1234
  }
];
```

I am using react-Redux for a framework for my application the "mydata" is the response from the backend.  I need to change by date wise. need to separate by "source"  and "Registernumber" is that possible.?

Comment: Hey can  you tell what have you tried and where did you face the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
var mydata = [
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul1": 1004
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul2": 1234
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul3": 1034
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul4": 1204
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul5": 2234
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul6": 2234
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul7": 2034
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul8": 2412
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul9": 2502
   },
   {
      "source": 11,
      "Registernumber": ">RT-113, <RT-333",
      "jul10": 1122
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul1": 1034
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul2": 1304
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul3": 1230
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul4": 2234
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul5": 2234
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul6": 2224
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul7": 2232
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul8": 1434
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul9": 1244
   },
   {
      "source": 12,
      "Registernumber": ">GF-103, <GF-303",
      "jul10": 1234
   }
]

const parseData = (mydata) => {
  const sources = mydata.map(item => item.source).filter( (value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index )
  const res = []
  sources.map(source => { 
    let d = {}
    mydata.filter(item => (item.source === source )).forEach(item => { d = {...d, ...item} })
    res.push(d)
  })

  return res
}

console.log(parseData(mydata))
```

Comment: You should use forEach instead of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#When_not_to_use_map) and `[...new Set(mydata.map(item => item.source))]` is quicker to remove doubles than filter

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce:

```
Object.values(
  mydata.reduce((result, item) => {
    result[item.source] = {//group by source property
      ...result[item.source],//merge items with same source
      ...item,
    };
    return result;
  }, {})
);
```

Working snippet:

```js
const mydata = [
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul1: 1004,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul2: 1234,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul3: 1034,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul4: 1204,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul5: 2234,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul6: 2234,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul7: 2034,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul8: 2412,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul9: 2502,
  },
  {
    source: 11,
    Registernumber: '>RT-113, <RT-333',
    jul10: 1122,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul1: 1034,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul2: 1304,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul3: 1230,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul4: 2234,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul5: 2234,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul6: 2224,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul7: 2232,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul8: 1434,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul9: 1244,
  },
  {
    source: 12,
    Registernumber: '>GF-103, <GF-303',
    jul10: 1234,
  },
];
const result = Object.values(
  mydata.reduce((result, item) => {
    result[item.source] = {
      ...result[item.source],
      ...item,
    };
    return result;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```